# Android:how to convert px into sp

Tags: android

I want calculate the sp value from pixels so, what is the sp (Scale-independent Pixels) value for 33px? and is there any formula to calculate sp from px?

Comment: sp = px / DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity

Answer (score 1):

This is the equation.
    **sp = px / DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity**.
  By using the below function you can do your stuff.

You can use below method as well .

```
public static float pixelsToSp(Context context, Float px) {
    float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px/scaledDensity;
}
```